What distinction is Paul making by saying "things in heaven" in the dative and "things on earth" in the genitive?
Ephesians 1:10 (ESV)

as a plan for the fullness of time, to unite all things in him, things in heaven and things on earth.


εἰς οἰκονομίαν τοῦ πληρώματος τῶν καιρῶν ἀνακεφαλαιώσασθαι τὰ πάντα ἐν τῷ Χριστῷ τὰ ἐπὶ τοῖς οὐρανοῖς καὶ τὰ ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς ἐν αὐτῷ

Paul puts things in heaven in the dative and things on earth in the genitive. Usually they both in the same case (cf. Exodus 20:11, Acts 4:24, 14:15).
What distinction is Paul making by saying things in heaven in the dative and things on earth in the genitive?

Koine Greek is not as pedantic about the distinction between dative and genitive as some might think - the two cases were often used (in some places) almost interchangeably.  This is a perfect example.  In this case, the waters are further "muddied" by the fact that "heavens" is masculine plural; while "earth" is feminine singular.  Genitive is sometimes used for the accusative as well as here.

@Dottard That may be true, but the norm is accusative for both expressions. This strikes me as purposeful. So to what end?

I believe the distinction is future Israel after receiving their promised kingdom of heaven (on earth) for Christ's millennial reign, and the heavenly ecclesia the church, the body of Christ.  With these two entities (both being 'in Christ') coming together as one at the "fulness of times".

+1 It's good to question the assumption that there is just no difference.

Concerning the preposition, ⲉⲡⲓ, BDAG lists this:
ἐπί prep. w. gen., dat., or acc.; s. the lit. on ἀνά, beg. (Hom.+). The basic idea is ‘upon’ (opp. ὑπό) Kühner-G. I 495; s. also Rob 600–605. (In the foll. classifications case use is presented seriatim; in earlier editions of this lexicon all sections, except 13, 17, and 18 [of time], were included under the general rubric ‘Place’.)
    1. marker of location or surface, answering the question ‘where?’ on, upon, near
    a. w. gen., marking a position on a surface ἐ. (τῆς) γῆς on (the) earth (cp. En 9:1; 98:1; ἐ. γῆς 25:6; PsSol 17:2) Mt 6:10, 19; 9:6; 23:9; Mk 6:47 al. (Ar. 12, 1; Just., A I, 54, 7 al.). ἐ. τῆς θαλάσσης on the sea (cp. Job 9:8; Dio Chrys. 10 [11], 129 βαδίζειν ἐ. τῆς θαλ.; Lucian, Philops. 13 βαδίζειν ἐφ̓ ὕδατος, VH 2, 4; Artem. 3, 16 ἐ. τ. θαλάσσης περιπατεῖν; schol. on Nicander, Ther. 15 p. 5, 26ff relying on the testimony of Hesiod: Orion was given a gift [δωρεά] by the gods καὶ ἐ. κυμάτων πορεύεσθαι καὶ ἐ. τῆς γῆς) Mt 14:26; Mk 6:48f; J 6:19 (w. acc. P75; s. 4bβ below). ἐ. τῶν νεφελῶν on the clouds Mt 24:30; 26:64 (Da 7:13; cp. Philo, Praem. 8). ἐ. κλίνης 9:2; Lk 17:34. ἐ. τοῦ δώματος on the roof vs. 31; Mt 24:17; 10:27 foll. by pl. W. verbs: κάθημαι ἐ. τινος sit on someth. (Job 2:8; ἐ. τοῦ ἅρματος GrBar 6:2; cp. JosAs 27:1 ἐ. τοῦ ὀχήματος καθεζόμενος; Just., D. 90, 5 ἐ. λίθου καθεζόμενος) Mt 24:3; 27:19; Ac 8:28; Rv 6:16; 9:17 (the same prep. used in Rv w. κάθημαι and dat. s. bα below, and w. acc. cα). ἑστηκέναι ἐ. τινος stand on someth. Ac 21:40; Rv 10:5, 8 (Just., D. 86, 2 ἐστηρίχθαι). With parts of the body: ἐ. χειρῶν αἴρειν carry on (i.e. in/with) their hands Mt 4:6; Lk 4:11 (both Ps 90:12). ἐ. κεφαλῆς on the head (Hdt. 5, 12, 4) J 20:7; 1 Cor 11:10; Rv 12:1. ἐ. τοῦ μετώπου Rv 7:3; 9:4. ἐ. γυμνοῦ on the naked body Mk 14:51. Cp. use of ἐπί w. καθίζω and gen., and ἐπί w. κάθημαι and acc. Mt 19:28.—In a gener. and fig. sense Ac 21:23.
    b. w. dat., gener. suggesting contiguity on, in, above.
    α. answering the question ‘where?’ (Hom. et al.; ins, pap, LXX; Just., D. 105, 5 ἐ. τῷ σταυρῷ; Tat., 9:1 ἐ. τοῖς ὄρεσι; Ath. 20, 1 ἐ. τῷ μετώπῳ; Mel., P. 19, 131 ἐ. σάκκῳ καὶ σποδῷ) ἐ. πίνακι on a platter Mt 14:8, 11; Mk 6:25, 28. ἀνακλῖναι ἐ. τῷ χλωρῷ χόρτῳ on the green grass 6:39. ἐ. τοῖς κραβάττοις vs. 55. ἐπέκειτο ἐπ̓ αὐτῷ lay on it (or before it) J 11:38. καθήμενος ἐ. τῷ θρόνῳ Rv 4:9 (cp. gen. w. καθ. 1a above, and acc. cα below) 5:13; 7:10 and oft. ἐφ̓ ἵπποις λευκοῖς on white horses 19:14. ἐ. σανίσιν on planks Ac 27:44. ἐ. τῇ στοᾷ in the colonnade 3:11. τὰ ἐ. τοῖς οὐρανοῖς what is above (or in) the heavens Eph 1:10. ἐπ̓ αὐτῷ above him, at his head Lk 23:38 (=Mt 27:37 ἐπάνω τ. κεφαλῆς αὐτοῦ).
    β. answering the question ‘whither?’ on, upon (Hom. et al.) w. verbs that indicate a direction: οἰκοδομεῖν ἐ. τινι build upon someth. Mt 16:18. ἐποικοδομεῖν Eph 2:20. ἐπιβάλλειν ἐπίβλημα ἐ. ἱματίῳ παλαιῷ put a patch on an old garment Mt 9:16. ἐπιπίπτειν ἐ. τινι Ac 8:16. ἐκάθισεν ἐ. τῷ θρόνῳ he sat down on the throne GJs 11:1. λίθον ἐπ̓ αὐτῇ βαλέτω J 8:7 v.l. (cp. 12a below).

(BDAG, s.v. “An Introduction to the Lexicon of the Greek New Testament,” paragraph 41.)

We note the basic usage:

In the genitive, ⲉⲡⲓ (especially when attached to "earth", ⲅⲏ) means "on top of). And so it answers the question, "on top of what?" (much like "auf dem Tisch" in German)
In the dative, it, in a broad way, answers the question, "where"

That, most likely, however, is the most we can say about the use of the prepositions.  It is not wise to press too much exegetical weight into prepositions like this for the following reasons:

Much of the harder (more precise) edges of grammar are rubbed off in Koine usage (as an example, cf. any grammar about the distinction between ⲁⲡⲟ/ⲉⲕ and ⲉⲓⲥ/ⲉⲛ)
There is much influence of Hebrew/Aramaic on NT Greek usage. The NT authors were more flexible in their usage of prepositions due to the innate flexibility of the prepositions they knew in their native language (e.g. ב in Hebrew). That flexibility shows itself in NT usage. Again, look in any grammar concerning "Aramisms" and you'll find enough context to see linkages between OT Hebrew and NT Greek.
In poetry grammar gets compressed. So, one of the first parts of grammar that either gets reshaped or thrown out is the prepositions. (cf. 1 Pet. 3:18, where we'd like a whole lot more grammatical words to work with, but instead, we get piles of parallelism)

There are times that the syntax is important. For example, in NT usage we are saved "by" faith. But we are never saved "because of faith" (ⲇⲓⲁ ⲡⲓⲥⲧⲓⲛ). Faith is not a decision we make. Instead, it's a gift given to us through the power of God's word (cf. 1 pet. 1; James 1; Rom. 10, etc). But even in this, there is flexibility in the expression of that.  The "by" faith is expressed ...

In the dative (ⲡⲓⲥⲧⲉⲓ)
In the genitive (ⲉⲕ ⲡⲓⲥⲧⲉⲱⲥ)

With all this in mind it's best not to press the particles beyond what they can bear.
